# Geometric Interpretation of Fractional Derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis, fractional-calculus, geometric-interpretation

I was looking for a geometrical interpretations of **fractional derivatives** and **fractional integrals**.

I would be glad to see any kind of intuitive and preferably visual interpretation of the objects of *fractional calculus*.

Can anyone recommend the source or share personal opinion on the topic?

Comment: [In this thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171923/physical-intuition-interpretation-of-fractional-derivatives-integrals/175180#175180) I answer a very similar question, pointing out how they emerge in stochastic dynamics.

Comment: @NikolajK, your answer looks depressingly complicated. Isn't there a simpler way of depicting concepts of fractional calculus?

Comment: There are various interprations, depending on the domain of application considered in physics. For example, in electrotechnics :https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire  . Concerning pure geometrical interpretation, see : http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110241.pdf

Comment: @JJacquelin Thank you, I'll have to go through it and try to extract a short and self-contained example or illustration

Comment: @JJacquelin that "geometric" interpretation is nothing more than its area projected with a gamma function. Most can parse that from the formula. Plus there's not really a way to construct that without using non geometric methods.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following link

[www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/rmf/v60n1/v60n1a6.pdf](http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/rmf/v60n1/v60n1a6.pdf)

about "A physical interpretation of fractional calculus" and,

[vectron.mathem.pub.ro/dgds/v15/D15-ta.pdf](http://vectron.mathem.pub.ro/dgds/v15/D15-ta.pdf)

entitled "The geometric and physical interpretation of fractional order."

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{1/2} x^a = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1/2)} x^{a-1/2}$$ and $$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{1/2} e^{ax} = \sqrt{a} e^{ax}$$ so it's look cool, but unfortunately it's not local : the distribution filter to get $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{1/2} f$  from $f$ is not point-wise as $\delta'(x)$ :

$$f'(x) = [f \ast \delta'](x)$$

$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{1/2}f(x) = [f \ast d_{1/2}](x)$$ (where $\ast$ is the convolution) but $d_{1/2}(x)$ is not even supported on a finite interval. it means that from the Taylor series or the Fourier series of a function it's easy to calculate the $1/2$th derivatives, but from a simple function such as $1/\sin(x)$ it becomes much more difficult, and even impracticable.